# json_encode slow

Tags: php, json

When I am getting 3 records from MySQL and exporting to json with json_encode the php file is loading 0.5 seconds, but when I am getting and exporting 6 records then it is loading 15 seconds. I found that when I will comment json_encode then php file is loading 0.5 seconds with no matter if I am getting 3, 6, 12 or more records, so the problem is somerwhere with json_encode. Is it any possibility to export those 6 recordes to json faster?

One record contain 12 rows with approximatelly 500 characters per record.

One record from json:

```
["7","49-z-zamiast-250-z-za-lifting-bez-skalpela-nieinwazyjny-i-bezbolesny-zabieg-na-wybran-parti-twarzy-w-salonie-motylem-jestem-na-warszawskim-bemowie","49 z\u0142 zamiast 250 z\u0142 za lifting bez skalpela - nieinwazyjny i bezbolesny zabieg na wybran\u0105 parti\u0119 twarzy w Salonie \"Motylem Jestem\" na warszawskim Bemowie","49","250","80",148448,"67b9e57e02b409cd60f3f9745b9c9073","80% rabatu - 49-z-zamiast-250-z-za-lifting-","Zdrowie i Uroda","Frupi","Warszawa"]
```

a bit of php code:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$slug=$row['slug'];
$short_title=$row['deal_save_percent']."% rabatu - ".substr($slug,0,30);
$title=$row['deal_title'];
$price=$row['deal_price'];
$price_old=$row['deal_face_value'];
$discount=$row['deal_save_percent'];
$end_time=$row['deal_oe_end_date']-$ts;
$image_url=md5($row['deal_image_url']);
$category_name=$row['category'];
$website=$row['web_site'];
$city=$row['city'];

$arr[]=array('0'=>$id, '1' => $slug, '2' => $title, '3' => $price, '4' => $price_old, '5' => $discount, '6' => $end_time, '7' => $image_url, '8' => $short_title, '9' => $category_name, '10' => $website, '11' => $city);
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of these rows, it sounds really odd it would take that long.

Comment: Show some code. Profile with `var_export` or `serialize` alternatively to figure out if it's the format specifically, or lazy loading and variable state otherwise.

Comment: I added code to my question. Also I check with serialize and var_export and it is the same. 15 seconds for 6 records. The more strange is this that when I will get and export 12 records then it takes just 0.2 seconds longer than for 6 records.

Comment: And did you profile the mysql_fetch_assoc-loop or the whole script? What happens if you try PDO et al?

Comment: Sorry, but I see that I didnt get you, because I just changed json_encode to var_export and serialize. Can you tell me how can I profile mysql_fetch_assoc-loop or the whole script, as I dont know? I have checked also PDO and it is still the same. The one thing what I have found with a few tests is this, that when I am not exporting to json `$title` (with polish letter) and `$image_url` (md5) is working fast. Do you know what can couse that $title and $image_url cause this delay? Looks like lenght of those variables, but why?

Comment: @Marek You can follow this article on how to profile php scripts: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: @Marek Can you tell us what type and version of SQL you are using, as well as the version of your PHP?

Comment: @Kris thanks for asking about type. I have checked my database and I found that collation of tables is latin1_swedish_ci (fields in tables utf8_general_ci). After changing collation of tables to utf8_general_ci everything is alright.

Comment: No worries, I will just post an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check your PHP and MySQL version and settings, there might be something wrong inthere like wrong collation settings. :)